# Seperate Network Cards - Clients cannot resolve

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dhcp, domain-controller

I have a domain controller that is also a DNS server for our internal clients it has two network cards within the Machine, presently one of them is disabled and the other is configured in the following :

```
IP Address : 10.0.0.4
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 10.0.0.60 

DNS Server : 10.0.0.4
```

I want to setup the other network card with a completely seperate IP Address so that i can configure DHCP on that card to lease addresses, however when ever i setup the second card and enable it, all the domain clients loose internet access.

the details i am entering in the second card are as follows.

```
IP Address : 172.20.10.1
Subnet : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 172.20.10.254 

DNS Server : 10.0.0.4
```

What am i doing wrong? the minute i disable the second card again, the clients regain internet access and are able to work as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a separate gateway set for the second card, unless that is also a valid route to all external networks.

The second gateway will become the default one when you enable it, losing the first one.

The DHCP pool SHOULD push a separate gateway to the clients, but that would be the same IP as you assigned to the card, i.e. 172.20.10.1

Comment: am i correct in thinking that by providing the ip of the network card as the gateway(router) address when clients from the DHCP pool request internet access they would come back to this PC, the 172 nic card would then divert the request to the 10.0.0.60 address?

Comment: The DC would route the traffic wherever it is meant to go.